# How to detect the mouse click from browser triggered by Enter key press?

Tags: javascript, html

I notice that on modern browsers such as Chrome, when placing one text field and one button within a form element. If enter key is pressed from the text field, the button will get clicked with a mouse click event issued by browser.

Since the only button within the form isn't used for submitting the form, is there a way for that button to only accept user click instead of browser click?

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
  <input type="text"/>
  <button id="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function() {
  alert("button clicked");
}
```

https://codepen.io/stevenz1987/pen/poEBmqv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the "type" attribute to the "button" element. Like below:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  debugger;
  alert(123);
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
  <input type="text"/>
<button type="button" id="btn">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Or alternatively use `<input type="button" id="btn" value="submit">`

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't happen because it's the *only* button in the form, but rather because it's a `submit` button.

[`<button>` elements default to `type="submit"` when associated with a form.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attributes)

To disable that behavior, set the `type` attribute to `button` manually:

```
<button id="btn" type="button">Submit</button>
```

[Try it on CodePen](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/rNMbEXv)

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's a good learning.